# Django Error Reporting Email when Debug = True

Tags: python, django, django-email, django-errors

Is there a way to get Django to email me error reports even though I have debug set to True?

I didn't see anything in the docs.

Edit:

I'm on Django 1.2 if it matters.
No, this isn't a production system.

Comment: There is no option for this as far as I know. What you could do perhaps is write your own [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#SafeExceptionReporterFilter.get_traceback_frame_variables) ("See also" note under the linked paragraph is talking about this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at [django-sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry). It's really designed for use in production, but it has `TESTING` setting to make it work when `DEBUG=True` as well. It might actually send out emails at that point, too -- haven't tested that myself, but it'll at least keep a log of errors that you can view at any time from any web-enabled device.

Besides, when you do eventually go to production, it'll be a life-saver.

Answer (score 6):

If you only have one email, make sure you have a comma in the list:

```
ADMINS = (('Admin', 'admin@my-domain.com'),)
```

I tried these and seems work:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on Bob Roberts answer a bit, I found the default logging configuration in `django.utils.log`. You can just copy and paste it to your settings, name it `LOGGING`, and change the line:

```
# settings.py:
# copied from django.utils.log import DEFAULT_LOGGING
LOGGING = {
    ...
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            # emails for all errors
            #'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'filters': [],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can achieve that by specifying an empty list to the filters associated with your AdminEmailHandler defined in your settings.py.

For instance:

```
'mail_admins': {
    'level': 'ERROR',
    'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
    'filters': []
}
```

By default the filters for this class would be a django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line to your settings.py file should do the trick.

```
LOGGING['handlers']['mail_admins']['filters'] = []
```